# Jdk failed to compile my code that throws exception inside Runnable

Tags: java, exception, runnable, throw

I'm trying to throw exception from within a Runnable object, like this:

```
  class ExceptionRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
      throw new Exception("ExceptionRunnable");
    }
  }
```

Compilation error: xxx.ExceptionRunnable.run() doesn't implement java.lang.Runnable.run(). The overriden run() doesn't throw java.lang.InterruptedException.

This is really odd, I'm throwing a `new Exception` in the `run` function, but compiler said I didn't throw anything. I'm using jdk1.8 on windows.

How to handle this?

Comment: The run method in the `Runnable` class does not have `throws Exception` so you can not override it like that. To fix this simply remove `throws Exception` from here `public void run() throws Exception {` like so `public void run() {` and instead throw the exception from within the method as you are already doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling your code:

```
class ExceptionRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("ExceptionRunnable");
    }
}
```

The compiler shows the following error:

```
java: run() in ExceptionRunnable cannot implement run() in java.lang.Runnable
  overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception
```

Why? Because the method you're overriding - [`Runnable.run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--) - has this signature (note the absence of a `throws` clause):

```
void run()
```

To fix the first issue then, change your code from this:

```
public void run() throws Exception {
```

to this, so that the signatures match:

```
public void run() {
```

After making that change, you will uncover the next compiler error:

```
java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

This is saying that your own code is throwing an `Exception` which is both not caught and not declared in the throws clause. You've already found that you can't add it to the throws clause though – that's what you initially tried to do. So the other option would be to catch the exception in your `run()` method, like below:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        throw new Exception("ExceptionRunnable");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another option would be to throw a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), like below, but you should *only* do this with intention, fully understanding what it means to introduce unchecked exceptions into your code.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    throw new RuntimeException("ExceptionRunnable");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a similar question has been asked before:  [Java : How to override a method and throw exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333260/java-how-to-override-a-method-and-throw-exception)

Would throwing a RuntimeException meet your requirement?

```
  class ExceptionRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      throw new RuntimeException("ExceptionRunnable");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the rules of *method overriding* can not declare to throw **checked exceptions** (or their super types up to `Throwable`) that not declared by parent while overriding the method in the subclass.

A quote from the [*Language specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> If m2 has a **throws clause** that mentions any **checked exception** types,
> then m1 must have a throws clause, or a **compile-time error occurs**.

Such situation when child has less safe behavior that its parent also voilates the [*Liskov substitution principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states that client code that expects an instance of the parent should be able to use its child without knowing it. Because in case when child has less safe behavior, the client would not be to handle it with the code that is suitable for the parent.

Super type `Exception` is *checked* (i.e. compiler should ensure that it's handled properly whenever might occur) and method `run()` doesn't declare to throw any *checked exception*, therefore you can't override `run()` by including `Exception` in the `throws` close.

You can include any type of *unchecked exception* in the `throws` close of `run()`. The code below is valid and would compile:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() throws RuntimeException {
        // todo
    }
}
```

All *checked exceptions* that your code might throw should be handled inside `run()` and can not be propagated to the caller:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() throws RuntimeException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* avoid declare to `throw` as well as avoid catching super types like `Exception`, or `Throwable`, it's a bad habit. Be as much specific as it's possible