# Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in Server.main(String[])

Tags: java, exception, throws

I'm running the Lip reading code on Eclipse Indigo from the following link : 
https://github.com/sagioto/LipReading/blob/master/lipreading-core/src/main/java/edu/lipreading/WebFeatureExtractor.java

```
package main.java.edu.lipreading;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.BytePointer;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core;
import main.java.edu.lipreading.vision.AbstractFeatureExtractor;
import main.java.edu.lipreading.vision.NoMoreStickersFeatureExtractor;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketHandler;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_8UC1;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvMat;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvDecodeImage;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Sagi
 * Date: 25/04/13
 * Time: 21:47
 */
public class WebFeatureExtractor extends Server {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WebFeatureExtractor.class.getSimpleName());
    private final static AbstractFeatureExtractor fe = new NoMoreStickersFeatureExtractor();

    public WebFeatureExtractor(int port) {
        SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
        connector.setPort(port);
        addConnector(connector);

        WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
            public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest request, String protocol) {
                return new FeatureExtractorWebSocket();
            }
        };
        setHandler(wsHandler);
    }

    /**
     * Simple innerclass that is used to handle websocket connections.
     *
     * @author jos
     */
    private static class FeatureExtractorWebSocket implements WebSocket, WebSocket.OnBinaryMessage, WebSocket.OnTextMessage {

        private Connection connection;


        public FeatureExtractorWebSocket() {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * On open we set the connection locally, and enable
         * binary support
         */
        @Override
        public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
            LOG.info("got connection open");
            this.connection = connection;
            this.connection.setMaxBinaryMessageSize(1024 * 512);
        }

        /**
         * Cleanup if needed. Not used for this example
         */
        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String message) {
            LOG.info("got connection closed");
        }

        /**
         * When we receive a binary message we assume it is an image. We then run this
         * image through our face detection algorithm and send back the response.
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessage(byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
            //LOG.info("got data message");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bOut.write(data, offset, length);
            try {
                String result = convert(bOut.toByteArray());
                this.connection.sendMessage(result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.severe("Error in facedetection, ignoring message:" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String data) {
            LOG.info("got string message");
        }
    }
    public static String convert(byte[] imageData) throws Exception {
        opencv_core.IplImage originalImage = cvDecodeImage(cvMat(1, imageData.length, CV_8UC1, new BytePointer(imageData)));
        List<Integer> points = fe.getPoints(originalImage);
        if(points == null)
            return "null";
        String ans = "";
        for (Integer point : points) {
            ans += point + ",";
        }
        return ans;
    }



    /**
     * Start the server on port 999
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebFeatureExtractor server = new WebFeatureExtractor(9999);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

In the following line :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
Exception Exception is not compatible with throws clause in Server.main(String[])
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two condition you need to check.
1) when declaring a method in interface you need to add throws exception for that method and similarly with the interface implementation class where the method is implemented.
for example
service.java

```
@Component
public interface UserService {

    User getUser(Login login) throws Exception;
    }

serviceimpl.java
public User getUser(Login login)throws Exception 
    {   

       }
```

2) by doing the above statement the error still doesn't vanish. make sure to save both the files.

Answer (score 0):

Doest the server API handle all exceptions for itself. Why not try removing the throws in your code. I know its not good programming practice but might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Server` class you are extending *already contains* a `public static void main(String[])` method that **does not** have the same `throws` declaration. I didn't take a look at it, but I'd bet that method doesn't throw anything at all.

A solution would be to remove your throws clause in your `main` method and rely on try-catches instead.

**EDIT**: Why you cannot add a different `throws` clause in your case.

Let's assume the following scenario:

```
class A {
    public static void foo() throws SomeException { ... }
}

class B extends A {
    public static void foo() throws DifferentException { ... }
}
```

The Java standard says you are *hiding* the `A.foo()` method (or at least trying to). Thing is, you're only allowed to do that **if** the throws clause in `B.foo()` is *already contained* in the clause of `A.foo()`. So for the above scenario, you're perfectly legal **only if** `DifferentException` is a subclass of `SomeException`. Otherwise the compiler will yell.

Comment: Or just put the new `main` in a different class.

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case I have implemented a method from an interface that did not declared to throw an exception.

In your case, I would guess that Server class also has a main method that didn't throw an exception.  To quickly solve it.  I would declare Server.main to throw an exception.

This link helped me

[What are reasons for Exceptions not to be compatible with throws clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513374/what-are-reasons-for-exceptions-not-to-be-compatible-with-throws-clauses)