# Why adding throws InterruptedException creates compilation error for implementation of Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

Why in the code below "public void run() throws **InterruptedException**" creates a compilation error but "public void run() throws **RuntimeException**" does not?

The compilation error raised by InterruptedException is"Exception InterruptedException is not compatible with throws clause in Runnable.run()"

Is it because RuntimeException is unchecked exception therefore does not change the run() signature?

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{
String name;
public MyThread(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public void run() throws RuntimeException{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Math.round(100*Math.random()));
            System.out.println(i+" "+name);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread (new MyThread("Jay"));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread (new MyThread("John"));
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

}
```

}

Comment: "Is it because RuntimeException is unchecked exception therefore does not change the run() signature?" ... Yes.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513374/what-are-reasons-for-exceptions-not-to-be-compatible-with-throws-clauses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`run()` method as defined in the `Runnable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run()) does not list any exceptions in any `throws` clause, so it can only throw `RuntimeException`s.

When overriding a method, you cannot declare that it throws more checked exceptions than the method you're overriding.  However, `RuntimeException`s don't need to be declared, so they don't affect the `throws` clause.  It's as if an implicit `throws RuntimeException` is already there.

The [JLS, Section 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) states:

> A method that overrides or hides another method, including methods that implement abstract methods defined in interfaces, may not be declared to throw more checked exceptions than the overridden or hidden method.

Comment: Thank you "When overriding a method, you cannot declare that it throws more checked exceptions than the method you're overriding" made it clear.